# How to call 'call by value ' and 'call by reference' overloaded function?

Tags: c++, reference, overloading, lvalue

I have two overloaded functions, one "call by value" and the other "call by reference".

```
int f (int a)
{
    //code
}

int f (int &a)
{
    //code
}
```

But if I pass `const int`, it calls the "pass by value" function, why?

```
const int a=3;
f(a);//calls the call by value function.Why?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `a` is a `const int`, and so that tells the compiler that you do not wish to modify `a`. `a` can't be passed by reference (only by `const&`), because if it is a reference, `f` could modify it, but `f` is not allowed to because `a` is `const`.

So the only overload that is legal is the pass by value one - `int f(int a)`.

Comment: So, you want to say that we cant have such type of overload?

Comment: @ZeeshanAkhter What I mean is that your `a` can never be called by the "pass by reference" function

Comment: You can have one, `a` will just never be used to call it

Comment: Any way to call both of these functions?

Comment: @Zeeshan You can make the second one pass by `const` reference, but then the 2 functions would be ambiguous

Answer (score 4):

An lvalue of type `const int` cannot be converted to an lvalue of type `int` (because that would discard the qualification). So the `int&` overload is not viable, and the `int` overload wins by default. The argument of the function all undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the result is bound to the function parameter.